# Vertica include column names in output, but not row count footer

Tags: vertica, vsql

I am running some Vertica SQL queries from the command line and saving them to CSVs.

I want to keep column names, so I do not use the -t option. The problem is that I now am also left with the footer which gives the row count (e.g. (20 rows). I know that I could remove this footer in a separate command (as it will always be in the last row), but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

I have been looking at the documentation here:

https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/vsql/CommandLineOptions.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\pset footer off`.

More info on the metacommand is available at [the documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/#Authoring/ConnectingToVertica/vsql/Meta-Commands/psetNAMEVALUE.htm%3FTocPath%3DConnecting%2520to%2520Vertica%7CUsing%2520vsql%7CMeta-Commands%7C_____21).

Example:

```
dbadmin=> select count(*) from sessions;
 count
-------
     5
(1 row)

dbadmin=> \pset footer off
Default footer is off.
dbadmin=> select count(*) from sessions;
 count
-------
     5
```